# Spring boot drools integration not woking after drools updated from version 7.73.0.Final to 8.29.0.Final

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, drools

We were using spring boot+ drools maven dependency+drl files for implementing certain business rules in our spring boot application.We used the following drools dependencies(drools-core, drools-compiler, drools-decisiontables) with the version 7.73.0.The integration is not woking after drools updated from version 7.73.0.Final  to 8.29.0.Final.Please find the implementation and error trace below.Can someone help to resolve the same

My Config Class

```
@Configuration
public class DroolsConfig {

    private static final String RULES_DRL = "rules/rule-impl.drl";
    private static final KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();

    @Bean
    public KieContainer kieContainer() {
        KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
        kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(RULES_DRL));
        KieBuilder kb = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
        kb.buildAll();
        KieModule kieModule = kb.getKieModule();
        return kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());
    }

}
```

Calling class

```
 @Autowired
    private KieContainer kieContainer;

    public String applyCleansingRules(String name) {
         /////////
        KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
        /////
        kieSession.insert(name);
        kieSession.fireAllRules(1);
        kieSession.dispose();
        return /////
    }
```

Error Message :

```
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at com.rule.engine.RuleEngineApplication.main(RuleEngineApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kieContainer' defined in class path resource [com/rule/engine/config/DroolsConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer]: Factory method 'kieContainer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer]: Factory method 'kieContainer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.PatternBuilder.buildAnalysis(PatternBuilder.java:1597) ~[drools-compiler-8.29.0.Final.jar:8.29.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.PatternBuilder.buildEval(PatternBuilder.java:1499) ~[drools-compiler-8.29.0.Final.jar:8.29.0.Final]
```

Trace Junit Test :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '******Service': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'kieContainer'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kieContainer' defined in class path resource [com/rule/engine/config/DroolsConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer]: Factory method 'kieContainer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kieContainer' defined in class path resource [com/rule/engine/config/DroolsConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer]: Factory method 'kieContainer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer]: Factory method 'kieContainer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Your problem is not in how you fire the rules, it's in how you're creating your KieContainer bean. Instead of your 'fire rules' method, can you share how you instantiate the KieContainer, and an example simple DRL that causes this issue when you try and load it?

Comment: Also if you could include the stack trace of the UnsupportedOperationException you mentioned in the comments on Esteban's answer, that would help.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell. It seems that one of your rules is using something inside an `eval()` that is no longer supported in `8.29.0`.

You will need to start removing DRLs from your KieBase or commenting out rules containing `eval()` until you find the problematic one.

From the code, it could also be related to the `dialect` you are using. Are you specifying an explicit dialect for your rules?

Comment: no.. not using eval() anywhere. I tried commenting drl file still getting the error. It seems like spring+drools unable to create the kieContainer bean due to some changes that happened in drools version upgrade

Comment: Also got the below exception when kept only one simple case, (using java as dialect) Factory method 'kieContainer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: could you create a simple app reproducing this problem?